# Access a .pem public key from .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, environment-variables, public-key

I am storing a public key in a env variable as a string. This public key is from a .pem file. When I try to use it in my code, I get the following error

```
error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

I have tried what other users have suggested, by converting it to base64 and then using the key, but I still get the same error.

env variable for the public key

```
PUB_KEY='-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----randomgibberish-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

Code for converting it to base64

```
const pubKey = process.env.PUB_KEY
const buff = Buffer.from(pubKey).toString('base64');
console.log(buff)
```

Using it in the createPublicKey method here

```
crypto.createPublicKey({
                key: buff,
                format: 'pem',
            });
```

Any idea what could be going wrong? TIA

Comment: Well your variable names are a bit weird. `const privateKey = process.env.PUB_KEY` feels wrong to me. But I'd remove the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` from the ENV variable and append those (with a linebreak before begin and after end) in your code.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i edited the name. however, i tried running it without the begiin and end flags and it still fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is breaking because of line break in the public keys.

No need to use base64, I suggest you to use line breaks (\n) in env file to store the key just like this:

If assuming your key is something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlkH/R64I0H1awndlU1w6BseS9
5ygy2v6rwV7BA/xlNGCtWfsQ8UlbJl7fawZ1hgL7H8FcUkGk/RsWB7xRpUeHypnE
8UU2bbhaS+X8Bze2kdoayerb5+YK6kZlyPvmI+WVxksKUEChcKE+t83mqVpnQnO9
TkTXhzvual4cG+WatwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

then save is it like this (\n on the end of the line and making it a whole string, you can see how i have stored it)

```
export publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlkH/R64I0H1awndlU1w6BseS9\n5ygy2v6rwV7BA/xlNGCtWfsQ8UlbJl7fawZ1hgL7H8FcUkGk/RsWB7xRpUeHypnE\n8UU2bbhaS+X8Bze2kdoayerb5+YK6kZlyPvmI+WVxksKUEChcKE+t83mqVpnQnO9\nTkTXhzvual4cG+WatwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

And the in the code use:

```
const { publicKey } = process.env
const originalPublicKey = publicKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

This will do the work, it will generate your original keys.

```js
const publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlkH/R64I0H1awndlU1w6BseS9\n5ygy2v6rwV7BA/xlNGCtWfsQ8UlbJl7fawZ1hgL7H8FcUkGk/RsWB7xRpUeHypnE\n8UU2bbhaS+X8Bze2kdoayerb5+YK6kZlyPvmI+WVxksKUEChcKE+t83mqVpnQnO9\nTkTXhzvual4cG+WatwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'

const originalPublicKey = publicKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')

console.log(originalPublicKey)
```

then you can simply use this in your code.

```
crypto.createPublicKey({
                key: originalPublicKey,
                format: 'pem',
            });
```

Let me know in the comments, if have any issue after this too.

Answer (score 0):

Your key seems to be a PEM encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format. However, the line breaks are missing. These are to be set so that header and footer are each on a *single* line. In the body there is a line break after every 64 characters.

A correctly formatted PEM key can be processed *directly* by [`createPublicKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatepublickeykey). The key will be accepted even if the line breaks in the body are missing, but header and footer *must* be in different lines, otherwise the posted error message will be displayed: *error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line*.

Example:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')

var x509 = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAunF5aDa6HCfLMMI/MZLT
5hDk304CU+ypFMFiBjowQdUMQKYHZ+fklB7GpLxCatxYJ/hZ7rjfHH3Klq20/Y1E
bYDRopyTSfkrTzPzwsX4Ur/l25CtdQldhHCTMgwf/Ev/buBNobfzdZE+Dhdv5lQw
KtjI43lDKvAi5kEet2TFwfJcJrBiRJeEcLfVgWTXGRQn7gngWKykUu5rS83eAU1x
H9FLojQfyia89/EykiOO7/3UWwd+MATZ9HLjSx2/Lf3g2jr81eifEmYDlri/OZp4
OhZu+0Bo1LXloCTe+vmIQ2YCX7EatUOuyQMt2Vwx4uV+d/A3DP6PtMGBKpF8St4i
GwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

// Import
var importedPubKey = crypto.createPublicKey({
    key: x509,
    format: 'pem' // default, can also be omitted
});

// Export
console.log(importedPubKey.export({type: 'spki', format: 'pem'}))
```

The key can also be written as one-liner with line breaks as escape sequences (`\n`), e.g. for header and footer in single lines:

```js
var x509 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAunF5aDa6HCfLMMI/MZLT5hDk304CU+ypFMFiBjowQdUMQKYHZ+fklB7GpLxCatxYJ/hZ7rjfHH3Klq20/Y1EbYDRopyTSfkrTzPzwsX4Ur/l25CtdQldhHCTMgwf/Ev/buBNobfzdZE+Dhdv5lQwKtjI43lDKvAi5kEet2TFwfJcJrBiRJeEcLfVgWTXGRQn7gngWKykUu5rS83eAU1xH9FLojQfyia89/EykiOO7/3UWwd+MATZ9HLjSx2/Lf3g2jr81eifEmYDlri/OZp4OhZu+0Bo1LXloCTe+vmIQ2YCX7EatUOuyQMt2Vwx4uV+d/A3DP6PtMGBKpF8St4iGwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

All this also works if the key is stored in an environment variable (e.g. `X509ENV`) and retrieved (via `process.env.X509ENV`) as long as the line breaks are correctly taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is great, but the answer posted by @Ashishssoni meets my needs